Tag Text Element not showing only on mobile devices
Creating a webpage, i was using and eventListener in Javascript to add a title tag to an ul (listaComprados) in case the list didn't already have a title tag using the following:
if (listaComprados.querySelectorAll('title').length === 0) {
    const subtotal = document.createElement('title');
    subtotal.id = 'subtotal';
    listaComprados.appendChild(subtotal);
}

It worked fine, but when the site came live and I accessed it through mobile devices, the title tag did not show at all. Initially I was trying it with a span tag, so I already tried to change the tag and changed the display property to inline-block in css but it didn't work.
The page is available on https://kaiosingulano.github.io/sacolaDeCompras/ (it's in pt-br, my native language), and the said title tag should appear after pressing the "Comprar" button for the product.

What exactly are you expecting this [title}(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) tag to do? It's meant to go in the <head> element, not in the <body> and not to display text on the page itself.

Title goes to "head" section of the HTML. The one containing the page metadata. If you want to add list elements then you have to programatically create the list items and insert proper content in particular place. Title should not be placed in body of the page

I used a span tag initially. I needed a different text tag for the formula to work, since the "if" recognizes this different tag and not the other paragraphs that would be added. But the span tag didn't work and i searched for other tags that could be used to see if the error was indeed in the tag used, and ended up trying the title tag. It kept working the same way on desktop, but did nothing on mobile.

Why didn't the span tag work? It seems like you could easily add a class name to the span and then use that className in your if-statement.

yeah, i'm kinda learning the selectors yet, and opted for a direct tag selector, but to me its still a mistery why it did not work on mobile only. Guess i'll try to make this part static. It will be "uglier" but still functional.
